# Is setTimeout the right option for scheduling tasks spanning days?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am creating a user management system. There's an option for moderators to block users for a specific number of days. After receiving a block request, the disabled attribute for the user is set to true in the database. After the specified duration passes, the value is set back to false. The duration may range from 1 - 10 days. Is setTimeout() the right choice? Will it be cpu intensive if run for many users simultaneously?

Here's the function from my program. The complete program uses express as a server and mongoose to interact with the mongodb database.

```js
function disableUser(req,res) {

    let username = req.body.username;
    let app = req.body.app;
    let duration = req.body.duration;
    let reason = req.body.reason;

    User.find({username:username}).then((result) => {
        let user = result[0];
        user.disabled = true;
        user.save().then((user) => {
            disableMail(app, user.email, duration, reason); //send mail to user
            // schedule a task to set user.disabled to false after the duration
        }, (err) => {
            res.status(500).send(err);
        });
    }, (err) => {
        res.status(500).send(err);
    });

}
```

EDIT :
Seeing all the comments and answers, I think I'll implement something like this : store the end date of the ban (calculated using something like momentjs) along with the disabled attribute. A setInterval will run separately and check the date every 12 hours for all the users with disabled set to true. If the end_date matches the current date, the disabled attribute will be set to false.

Comment: You want to have a setTimeout that lasts over 1-10 days?  Seems a little excessive, and most likely wouldn't even work with the settings you probably have.  Definitely not necessary.  Post more details and some example code.

Comment: @user120242 I've added the function in question. And what do you mean by "wouldn't even work with the settings you probably have"? Are there any usage limitations for setTimeout?

Comment: a naive and basic attempt would be instead of disabled attribute, you would store date and extend this date with current ban duration. this user would be banned for a period of time.

Comment: @MücahidErenler So if I store the enable date in the database (by calculating it with something like momentjs), how do I schedule an unban on that date?

Comment: using that method, you could just calculate if they're banned or not

Comment: my idea was checking the ban date with the current date, to see if he is stil banned. this is pretty simple to implement imo. but if you still want to go for a schedule base solution, you need to implement some sort of background task tool. maybe check [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/)

Comment: A better solution would be to store bock status in database with number of days and run a cron  which will run periodically and watch, it will revert the status for any blocked user if time is due.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `setTimeout()` set for several days from now will work and it's not hardship on the server (even if you have a lot of them), but it's still probably not the right design choice for the following reasons:

1. `setTimeout()` is only good for the duration of your server running.  As soon as your server restarts for any reason (crash, planned maintenance, etc...), the `setTimeout()` is gone so even if you did use a `setTimeout()` you'd have to use a more durable means of storage anyway so you could restore all the timers on a server restart.
2. You don't need `ms` timing.  A multi-day ban can be removed hourly or even daily.

My suggestion is that instead of a timer, you run some periodic process that could be run once an hour that does a query to find any banned users whose ban has expired.  You will want to store the ban and the ban duration in the database in a way that makes this query efficient (perhaps in a separate table of banned users).  Then, you can run this query once an hour, remove the user from the banned table and then re-enable the "disabled" user attribute for those users whose ban has expired.

This type of design should meet all your objectives, is a durable way of storing the ban and can be implemented efficiently.

Comment: Seeing all the comments and answers, I think I'll implement something like this : store the end date of the ban (calculated using something like momentjs) along with the disabled attribute. A setTimeout will run separately and check the date every 12 hours for all the users with disabled set to true. If the end_date matches the current date, the disabled attribute will be set to false.

Comment: @Endemic - I'd check to see if the `end_date` is before or equal to the current date in case one ever gets missed.   If you ever get to a lot of users, you will have to evaluate whether querying all users in the database is efficient enough or if a disable users table is a more efficient design for the query.  But, not something to worry about until you get to a lot of users.

Answer (score 0):

Using setTimeout is probably impractical for a few reasons. First, you are correct that it would be intensive, especially if you have a lot of blocked users. Second, it wouldn't survive a server restart, which may occur because you are pushing new code.

If you go with some automated background task, then consider:

- You probably want to check if the user is blocked on all API calls and form submissions at the server-side. This could be part of your general security/permission checks on write calls.
- You'll need some error handling in the UI whenever a banned user's API call is rejected.
- You may want some background task that executes like once a minute and checks for blocked users and expires the ban when appropriate. A chron type job, or quartz (if Java), or something similar if on Node, can run the query and perform the updates.